# Adding a curve to Matlab Figure

Tags: matlab, plot

I have written a program that takes a lot of data and produces graphs.It would be really convenient and save me a lot of time if I could take curves on an existing figure and add their values together to make a single curve. For a simple example lets say I have the following code,

```
x = [0 1 2 3 4 5];
y = [0 1 2 3 4 5];
z = [4 6 2 8 7 9];

figure
plot(x,y,x,z)
```

This code will produce a figure with two curves. Without modifying the code or re-running the program, and only working with the figure options I would like to add the curve y + z to the plot. Is this possible? Thanks.

The reason I don't want to add the functionality is the plot code is buried within 8 loops 
that calls data from a 4D cell array of file name strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `x`, `y` and `z` variable used in the plot you can just add new lines to the plot with

```
hold on
plot(x,y+z)
hold off
```

If you don't have them directly (they were generated in a function, for example, you can always get them from figure with `XData`, `YData` properties of line objects.

```
hline = findobj(gca,'type','line');
x = get(hline,'XData');
y = get(hline,'YData');
X = x{1}; % let's assume that all lines have the same x values.
Y = sum(cell2mat(y));

hold on
plot(X,Y)
hold off
```